# Cannot edit value after filter in primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I have a datatable in primefaces having filtering capability, Every row is also having checkboxes. When I filter the values, and change checkbox value, then press save button, the changed value does not appear in the backend when I print them.
My datatable looks like:

```
<p:dataTable id="tbValues" widgetVar="kVar"  var="k" value="#{mybean.values}" paginatorPosition="top" paginatorTemplate="{PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport}
                {NextPageLink}" filteredValue="#{mybean.filteredValues}" scrollable="true" >
<p:column headerText="Name" filterBy="#{k.name}" >
        <h:outputText value="#{k.name}"/>
</p:column>
<p:column >
    <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Value1"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="v1" value="#{k.value1}"  immediate="true"/>
</p:column>
<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Value2"/>
    </f:facet>
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="v2" value="#{k.value2}" immediate="true" />
</p:column>
<f:facet name="footer">
<p:toolbar>
<p:toolbarGroup align="left">
    <p:commandButton id="saveBt" value="Save" update="tbValues" widgetVar="saveBt" actionListener="#{mybean.saveValues}"/>
</p:toolbarGroup>
</p:toolbar>
</f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

and my bean method is:

```
public void saveValues(ActionEvent event){
    System.out.println("filter: "+this.filteredValues);
    if(this.filteredValues!=null) {
        
        for(int i=0;i<this.filteredValues.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(this.filteredValues.get(i).isValue1()+" "+this.filteredValues.get(i).isValue2());
            
        }
    }
```

}

My Primefaces version: 10 
JSF: 2.2.15 
Wildfly: 23 
JDk: 16

Comment: Please try with PrimeFaces 11. A lot of data table issues have been fixed between 10 and 11.

Comment: I cannot update, any other fix or work around?